# ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/*.pid)

Tags: mysql, linux

I am trying to start mysql but I am getting this error again and again.. Why does this error occur? one my friend told me to copy file from **/etc/my.cnf to /etc/my.cnf.old**. But there is no such file in my filesystem. What should I do now?

Comment: Try this, maybe it will help you: http://icesquare.com/wordpress/mysql-starting-mysql-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file/

Comment: Swallowing my pride to admit I didn't reboot first, as a professional sysadmin. +1 to the link posted by @rMX.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Please help to fix
**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35794818/starting-mysql-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file-var-lib-mys**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have installed the server Package,right. For most linux distribution there is a server package and a client package. If so and the problem remains there are some sample files in **/usr/share/mysql/** which usually packaged in the server package called

*my-huge.cnf*

*my-innodb-heavy-4G.cnf*

*my-large.cnf*

*my-medium.cnf*

*my-small.cnf*

You could copy one of these files to **/etc/my.cnf** or you could try reinstalling the mysql server package.

Answer (score -1):

After trying several things, I went to System Preference on Mac, clicked on MySQL, unchecked "Automatically start mysql on startup" and restarted my machine. Oddly enough, that solved the problem for me. It it helpful to look at the error message in the .err file in the folder thats supposed to contain the pid file.